# Python Simple Websockets Server on CentOS refusing connection

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket, tcp, centos7

I have this python code which is a very simple websockets server (works on localhost):

```py
import asyncio
import re
import sys
from queue import Queue

import websockets

import exampl_script

client = None
async def new_client_connected(client_socket, path):
    global client 
    print("New Client Connected")
    client = client_socket
    while True:
        new_message = await client_socket.recv()
        print("Receivevd Message from the client")
        if new_message.endswith("."):
            new_message = re.sub(r'RECOGNIZED: Text=|。', '', new_message)
            exampl_script.cache += [new_message]
        
async def start_server():
    print("Server Started!")
    await websockets.serve(new_client_connected, '', port=12345, reuse_port=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    runners = []
    runners.append(start_server())
    exampl_script.main() 
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*runners))
    event_loop.run_forever()
```

Now, this script works perfectly on localhost (there is another script that it includes, however, it isn't the problem). JS tries to communicate with the websocket port 12345 (works on localhost).

When I migrated to VPS CentOs7.0 and after configuring everything for my webpage to work (and it does), it can't reach out the websockets port.

I have disabled all the firewalls like iptables, firewalld, etc.

I have made sure the application is listening to this port. Here is the output of lsof -i:12345

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 25461 root    6u  IPv6 321812      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25461 root    7u  IPv4 321813      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25462 root    6u  IPv6 321800      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25462 root    7u  IPv4 321801      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25463 root    6u  IPv6 321807      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25463 root    7u  IPv4 321808      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25464 root    6u  IPv4 320792      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25464 root    7u  IPv6 320793      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25692 root    6u  IPv4 323315      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
python3 25692 root    7u  IPv6 323316      0t0  TCP *:italk (LISTEN)
```

Here is the output of sudo netstat -nltp

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1112/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12345           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25692/python3
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25414/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1112/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::12345                :::*                    LISTEN      25462/python3
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      25414/nginx: master
```

When I try (on the server) to do

```
python3 -m websockets "ws://localhost:12345"
```

It says connected. However, when I try from another computer/pc to connect to it using the server ip. It can't be reached (despite reaching the website over port 80 normally).

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,
Mahmoud

Comment: *"I have read and tried every single question in Stackoverflow regarding this issue and still can't find anything related! "* - this is definitely not true and this claim adds no information of what you actually read and tried - which means it does not add any value to your question. I've removed it. Anyway: the script is listening on all IPv4 on the system so there is some kind of firewall blocking the packets involved - either on your local system, or on the system your connect from or somewhere in between. So the problem is outside of your script.

Comment: I have stopped all firewall services on the VPS like firewallcmd and iptables. The client is just a normal webpage that connects to WebSockets Python Server, and it uses the correct port/address of the server as well.

Comment: Like I said, there may be firewalls in between. Nothing is known about your VPS but in environments like AWS one usually also have to configure other firewalls then only the ones on the VM itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't thank you enough it might be a problem with Azure Portal as well, I didn't think about that! 

Thanks!

Comment: @Mahmoudamr Please share full url which you are using in the front end js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be two options:

1. check what source address the server use.
   It could be the source IP that the server use is not accessible from the client.
   You can run tcpdump on the server and check if the message received and reply is sent out.
2. FW rules on the VPC and security groups were not defined to allow ingress traffic for 12345 port.